# How can I convert total nanoseconds to string in format HH:MM:SS:ms:ns in JavaScript and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting back a time in total nanoseconds from an api. I need to be able to print out a time in the format HH:MM:SS:ms:ns. An example output would be "12:34:56.123456789".
JavaScript Date object only supports for the millisecond so what would be the best way to do this?

Desired functionality:

```
Input: 38145999999999
Output: 10:36:41.999999999
```

Comment: Simple math my friend, dividends and remainders. Start with how many nanoseconds are in an hour. Divide by that, then how many nanoseconds are in a minute, divide the remainder of the first division by that, etc. Or you can convert the nanoseconds to milliseconds and pass it to the Date object constructor. `1,000,000 Nanoseconds to Milliseconds = 1`

Comment: Also, how concerned are you with precision? If you divide your nanoseconds / 1000000 to get the milliseconds, what about any remaining nanos?

Comment: @RyanWilson I need it to be precise and output 9 digits after the decimal point. When I use Date, it gets me the time to the millisecond (3 digits after the decimal point) but sometimes also rounds down which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then I would suggest doing your own custom method which does the divisions and keeps the precision you want. Please add to your post of an example nanosecond value which matches your example output.

Comment: `ns=parseInt(1550000000000000000)%1000000; ms=1550000000000000000/1000000` do whatever you want with ms and at the end append the ns

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's function which will solve your problem:

```
function msToTime(duration) {
    var milliseconds = parseInt((duration%1000)/100)
    , seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
    , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
    , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24);

   hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
   minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
   seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

   return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
}
```

Comment: To create leading zero numbers, rather than testing for "X < 10 ? "0" + X : X", I use ("00" + X).substr(-2) ... {use more zeros and higher substr value as needed}   (or make it a function: function Lzero(x, digits) {return "00000000000000" + x.substr(0-digits);}